# Webpack is querying the wrong proxy port

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, django-rest-framework, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to build a React front end to consume a Django API. I am using Webpack and Webpack Dev Server, but it won't query the proxy port I tell it to. In fact, it always queries the specified front end port, or if I don't specify, the default one. I even tried hard coding `http://localhost:8000/feed/` into the GET request to see what would happen, and the answer is nothing. I'm using Webpack 4.8.3, and Webpack Dev Server 3.7.2 - both versions I've used with React and Django before and had no problem.

Here's some of my code:

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpack = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: "src/index.html",
  filename: "index.html",
  inject: "body"
});

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpack = new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: "./src/assets", to: "assets" }
]);

const HotModuleReplcement = new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin();

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("public"),
    filename: "app.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000" },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    open: true,
    port: 8080,
    proxy: {
      "**": {
        target: "http://[::1]:8000",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [HotModuleReplcement, HtmlWebpack, CopyWebpack]
};
```

The GET request, that's called in a componentDidMount of its component:

```
getSubmissions() {
        fetch('feed/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then((res) => this.setState({ submissions: res.data }))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
```

Package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 8080",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  }
```

I've also done a fair bit of Googling and tried a lot of different solutions, all of which made no difference. E.g. I tried the ones on this page already > https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/793